# Need to integrate the WorldPay in my app

Tags: android, worldpay

I need to integrate the WorldPay as a Payment Gateway into my android application.
I am referring the following link to integrate the Worldpay into my application.

https://developer.worldpay.com/jsonapi/docs/android

I have implemented all the scenarios as per mentioned in the documentation.

But when I am initializing the WorldPay it will ask for the "YOUR_CLIENT_KEY", Soo, I logged into the virtual terminal from the Worldpay sandbox account but there but from the key management I am only getting the Secure key and public key.

Soo can anyone help me from where I can generate the "CLIENT_KEY" for the application?

Also, another question is how can I generate the Token for the particular user, I am only getting the error on the "onResponseError" after calling the `worldpay.createTokenAsyncTask`.

Please help me out how do I integrate the proper integration, there is no other documentation is available there to get out of this.

Comment: https://developer.worldpay.com/jsonapi/docs/api-keys

Comment: how have you imported the WorldPay to your project? from where did you get the lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, we can't generate the client key for the test account on the WorldPay.
You have to create your request for create yopur account on http://online.worldpay.com .
Once you have your WorldPay account you will get your all account API keys from the following link:
[settings/keys](https://online.worldpay.com/settings/keys)

Here, you can get Service key and Client key for both test and live account.

You will get your token in the following method for the custom form:

```
createTokenAsyncTask = worldpay.createTokenAsyncTask(this, card, new WorldPayResponse() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ResponseCard responseCard) {
            Log.e("***+++","Token is : "+responseCard);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponseError(ResponseError responseError) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(WorldPayError worldPayError) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: When I try to register at http://online.worldpay.com, it redirects me to  https://www.pay360.com/. There after registering, there is no account confirmation. Just a message shows that we'll get back to you after one business day and then there is no contact. What to do? I need a client key